# Google Analytics for Android and Install referral

Tags: android, google-analytics, installation, referrer

if I include the code following code in AndroidManifest.xml, then will it send a notification on notification or there is something more to be included.

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
  android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

How to view installation report in Google Account and What parameters are required to be set in the account?

UA-Account number is the id to be used for websites, is it required for android app installation notification.

Can any one specify the exact procedure to view Android application installation in Google Analytics and coding snippets required.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of your questions are answered [here](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#gettingStarted).

In summary:

- You need to include the [Google Analytics SDK for Android](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/download.html)
- You need a UA number, which you provide when you call startNewSession: `tracker.startNewSession("UA-YOUR-ACCOUNT-HERE", this);`
- Google provides a fully functional [sample application](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#startingTheTracker) which starts/stops the `GoogleAnalyticsTracker` instance in your Activity and tracks events and page views, as well as dispatches the results (stored locally on the phone until dispatched to the analytics server)
- Include [AnalyticsReceiver](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#android-market-tracking) to track referrals

Comment: Thanks my friend. i am done with the above process, received data in google analytics. But the data is received in the Direct Sites , I am expecting it to be in Referring Sites. The format of my market url link is http://market.android.com/details?id=com.hello&referrer=utm_source%3Dsourcexyz%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dproduct

Comment: @niku22 updated answer to include the `receiver` you need to include to track referrals.